# How to manually start uv4l MJPEG stream for embedding in a web page?

Tags: raspbian, camera, streaming-video, uv4l

I recently found out about the new Raspberry Pi camera driver - [uv4l](http://www.linux-projects.org/modules/sections/index.php?op=viewarticle&artid=14)
I only have a b+ model, so unfortunately I can't use the WebRTC streaming.

I am okay with using the MJPEG, uv4l has a great example of an embedded MJPEG stream on the camera control page.

However - I don't know how do I start a stream manually, without using the control page, and how do I embed it in a web page (i.e. what do I put for the `src` attribute of the image?)

I would really appreciate any help with this.

So far I only found this man page: http://www.linux-projects.org/modules/sections/index.php?op=viewarticle&artid=13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I figured this out.

Once you access the stream URL (by default its `http://raspberry.com:8080/stream/video.mjpeg`) - the camera starts recording.

As soon as you stop reading from it - the camera stops.

So for example if, on your webpage you have the following html code for the stream:

`<img src="http://raspberry.com:8080/stream/video.mjpeg">` - just remove the `src` attribute so the browser stops sending requests for new frames and the camera will stop. To access the stream again - just puth the src url back.

Answer (score 0):

See this example at the homepage:[click here](http://www.linux-projects.org/modules/sections/index.php?op=viewarticle&artid=16#example11). It says:

> If you want to directly get the HTTP/MJPEG (Video) stream from the
>   server, e.g. with VLC, type from the client:
>
> ```
> client ~ $ cvlc http://raspberrypi:8080/stream/video.mjpeg
> ```

Therefore take the source URL above and embed it somewhere in your HTML page. Or just copy the HTML source to see how `UV4L` does it.

Comment: Thanks! But how do I start the camera to record the stream?
I am currently playing with this command:
`uv4l  --driver mjpegstream --uri URI `

Will update this post if I do come up with a solution to my original question.